# How to display custom attribute in cart (Magento)

Tags: php, html, magento, custom-attributes

I have tried a lot of stuf but none of them work. I think I can get the custom attributes on the product page, but I was wondering: how to get them in shopping cart page? (the attribute is just a simple written text)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`$_item->getProduct()->load()` will reload all product data from the database. While this will work, bear in mind that every time you call `load()` Magento will execute a database query.

The same can be done with much better performance by loading the attribute along with the quote item. Just create a custom module and add this to the config.xml

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <one_custom_attribute_code />
                    <another_custom_attribute_code />
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
```

Having done that, you can access your custom attribute without additional database queries.

```
$_item->getProduct()->getAnotherCustomAttributeCode();
```

Here is an article about this: https://www.atwix.com/magento/accessing-custom-attribute-at-checkout-or-cart/

Comment: This is by far the best answer

Comment: I agree with Rafael. This is the most efficient way to do it and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Definitely the best approach though Is there anyway to get the attribute's option label rather than option id with this approach?

Comment: You can try  `$_item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getStoreLabel();` to get the label.

Comment: @odd_duck `$_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_code')` should do the trick.

Comment: Does it require to change any template file ? I added custom price as attribute, getting this value in event successfully, but there are no changes in product's list or in checkout.

Answer (score 25):

Are you talking about custom option or simple attribute?

Simple attribute (text):
(In your default.phtml)

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

Comment: app/design/frontend/your_default/your_default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

Comment: Thanks on this, it works great :) Also, is there any way I can show if a product is out of stock or in stock. (for example: if it's available, what code should I use so it displays "In Stock"?)

Comment: we are talking about a select box, I'm not sure that this solution should works but you can try with $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('avability')->getSource()->getValue($_product);

Comment: Thanks on the help but that one didn't work. You can find a real solution to my second problem here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/247851/
Thanks for trying :)

Comment: -1 for two reasons: (1) calling load() inside of a loop. Because default.phtml gets included for each cart item (which Magento loops through) the page will load slowly with large carts. (2) If you must load within a loop, you can get the label text with getAttributeText('code') instead of getResource()->getAttribute('code')...etc.

Comment: The answer of @Andreas Riedmüller is by far better than loading the product. I don't get why this is the accepted answer.

Comment: @Simon My answer is quite old and it is not oriented in performance. I agree with you. Anyway it's a dirty but quick approach.

Answer (score 6):

I used this

(in `app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`)

for my (textfield) attribute:

```
<?php 
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_product = $_item->getProduct()->load();
?>
<?php echo $_product->getCustomAttribute(); ?>
```

Comment: $_product = $_item->getProduct()->load($_item->getProductId()); works

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the best way, in your Attribute (magento/admin) you can set the option:

Visible in Checkout

So the Attribute goes to the

```
$_options Array ($_options = $this->getOptionList()) (in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml)
```

You can use the Attribute (the array `$_option`) like:

```
array(4) { ["label"]=> string(10) "Lieferzeit" ["value"]=> string(8) "2-3 Tage" ["print_value"]=> string(8) "2-3 Tage" ["code"]=> string(13) "delivery_time" }
```

In this way you wont need to connect the database again and you optimize the performance.

Comment: This is a much better way than using `$_item->getProduct()->load();`. IMO every time `load` is used one should re-think what they're doing - load can be very intense and in fact slow down overall rendering performance.

The best method, however, is the one pointed out by Andreas Riedmüller above.

Comment: Where is this "Visible in Checkout" option in backoffice? I do not see this option when editing an attribute. I'm on 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Show **selected attribute from option list**:

Change in: app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
$_customOptions = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());

foreach($_customOptions['attributes_info'] as $_option){ echo option['label']; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible method is to use a *singleton* design pattern. Here is how to get an attribute.

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
echo $attrValue=$_product->getAttributeText('attrCode');
```

Answer (score 0):

Following all the contributions I've taken the 1st answer and wondered arround magento.

I found a solution that I didn't have to make the load() again. I've edited the file config.xml on the following path,

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
```

and on the item / product attributes I've added the custom attribute

```
<item>
    <product attributes>
        <sku/>
        <type_id/>
        <my_custom_attribute_id/>
```

then on my cart.phtml file I was able to get the attribute just by using:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getmy_custom_attribute_id();
```

I don't know if this is the best or the correct thing to do, but it sure solved the problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
                <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.