# How to show product custom options in checkout/cart page

Tags: magento

I want show custom options on cart page i tried using $_options = $this->getOptionList() but it only shows the selected option only , i want to retrieve all options.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/208939/ this link may be help you and also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213229/how-to-display-custom-attribute-in-cart-magento

Comment: Thanks but i need to display custom options not attributes :)

Answer (score 4):

To get product custom option value at cart page which are set at 'AddtoCart' time try with following code.

```
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllItems();
/* cart item loop */
foreach($cart as $item) {

/* This will get custom option value of cart item */
$_customOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

/* Each custom option loop */
foreach($_customOptions['options'] as $_option){
    echo $_option['label'] .'=>'. $_option['value']."<br/>";
    // Do your further logic here
   }
}
```

Already replied at 
[Display Magento Custom Option Values in Shoping Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992413/display-magento-custom-option-values-in-shoping-cart/18980004#18980004)

Answer (score 0):

You can get only selected options from using this function `$this->getOptionList()`, but if you actually want to retrieve all custom options then first of all you need to retrieve product id
You can get product like this on cart page

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_item->getProduct();
```

This will retrieve product from this you can get product and load product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getData('entity_id'));

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product);

    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
           print_r($o); // show all product options
        }
    }
```

Comment: AS i tested with my setup of magento it is working fine and it is listed all option in array like   _data: array = 
          option_id: string = "6"
          product_id: string = "28"
          type: string = "field"
          is_require: string = "1"
          sku: undefined = NULL
          max_characters: string = "0"
          file_extension: undefined = NULL
          image_size_x: undefined = NULL
          image_size_y: undefined = NULL
          sort_order: string = "0"
          default_title: string = "head title"

Comment: i m calling your code in this file /checkout/cart/item/default.phtml but it returns nothing

Comment: yes @liyakat : where to put this code for displaying all product custom option on cart page?